# How to query view in oracle with non column in view

Tags: oracle, view

I have created a view as

```
create or replace view view_emp as 
  select empno, ename, job 
    from emp;
```

and I want to query `view_query` with non column in view.

```
select empno, ename 
  from view_emp 
 where deptno=10;
```

When Im trying to  query like this it is giving me an error saying

```
ORA-00904: "TEST_EMP"."DEPTNO": invalid identifier
```

I have a requirement like this example. Could any one can give me solution for my requirement.

---

Actually I work on ERP Solutions Inventory Modules.

I have a requirement to find the unit wise , prodct wise stock opening balance and closing balance in date range.

I want a view like

```
create view stk_bal
     as
     select unit_code,prod_code, sum(opening_bal) opening_bal, sum(closing_bal) closing_bal
     from
     (
     select unit_code, prod_code, ob_qty opeing_bal, 0 closing_bal 
     from   (table 1) join (table 1.1)
     where crtd_date between '02-feb-2013' and '02-mar-2013'
     union all
     select unit_code, prod_code,  0 , grn_qty  
     from   (table 2) join (table 2.1)
     where grn_date between '02-feb-2013' and '02-mar-2013'
     union all
     select unit_code, prod_code,  0,  stk_transfer_in_qty 
     from   (table 3) join (table 3.1)
     where stk_trnin_date between '02-feb-2013' and '02-mar-2013'
     )
     group by unit_code, prod_code;
```

and I created view by making union all with 3 set of tables where i had hardcoded the dates
But i want to query the view in date range which has no date column in it.

Now I want to query the the view stk_bal in the date range.

Comment: But from where is it supposed to get the DeptNo when its not there in the definition of the view? A view is not its definition PLUS that of tables that made it. It is only its definition. You do not have deptno in "select empno, ename, job 
    from emp" Why do you need a view here?

Comment: Answer to your question - you cannot.

Comment: You should use google.com to read up on views and see some samples. and add what your real objective is here to this question if its still not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `deptno` in your view definition:

```
create or replace view view_emp as 
  select empno, ename, job
      ,DEPTNO
    from emp;
```

But of course, the real question is: what exactly is your requirement and why do you need a view.